# map legend not appearing with embedded google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

When I load a kmz file with the google map api v3.  The kmz file displays, but the legend that is part of the kmz file doesn't show.  I am new to this stuff, and I can t figure out how to do this.  I can look at the kmz file with google maps, and the legend data is there.  I can include code if needed, but this seems for of a general question, or api question

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a link to at least the KMZ file, the map if possible.

Comment: What legend do you mean? I don't see a legend on [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http:%2F%2Fww9.saskatoon.ca%2Fapp%2FqWardBoundaries%2Felection2012.kmz&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=m&z=11), I see a sidebar (on the left), is that what you mean?

Comment: yes, the sidebar legend on the left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sidebar is not created by default in the Google Maps API v3 (or v2) To make a sidebar for a KMZ file on a Google Maps API v3 map, you would need to use a third party KML parser like geoxml3 (from the kmz branch).

[Here is an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/election2012_kmz.zip) of a simple sidebar, using your KMZ file.

If you have a KML file, the [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) third party parser has a nice built in sidebar. [Here is an example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_dyasdesigns_com_geoxml_mtrmtrip.html).

Comment: Thanks, that's the information I needed.  How do you use geoxml-v3, the documentation seems to be lacking.  I would like to reorder the lengend items, but this isn't apparent how to do this.

Comment: Look at [Lance Dyas' page on GeoXml](http://www.dyasdesigns.com/geoxml/), there  are examples using the original (v2) GeoXml parser, I think the v3 version is compatible with that.  The other place to look for documentation is the [EGeoXml parser](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/egeoxml.htm), which is what Lance started with.